# How calculator time worked with 2 time different in google excel?

Tags: excel-2010

I have 2 time, time work in at 12/01/2023 9:00:00 AM and time work out at 13/01/2023 6:00:00 AM. But before 22:00:00, my salary is 13.000 and after 23:00:00 is 15.000. How can i calculator time before 23:00:00 and after 23:00:00

i used if(C3>B3,(C3-B3),if(B3>C3,C3+1,C3)-B3), but it only return total worked time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IF` and `AND` functions in Excel to calculate the time worked before 23:00:00 and after 23:00:00.

For example :

```
=IF(AND(C3>=B3, C3<TIME(23,0,0)), (C3-B3)*13000, IF(AND(C3>=TIME(23,0,0), C3<=TIME(24,0,0)), (C3-TIME(23,0,0))*15000, 0))
```

In this formula, the first `IF` statement checks if the time in cell `C3` is greater than or equal to the time in cell `B3` and less than 23:00:00. If that is true, it calculates the time worked before 23:00:00 by subtracting the time in cell `B3` from the time in cell `C3`, then multiplies that time by the hourly rate of 13000.

The second `IF` statement checks if the time in cell `C3` is greater than or equal to 23:00:00 and less than or equal to 24:00:00. If that is true, it calculates the time worked after 23:00:00 by subtracting 23:00:00 from the time in cell `C3` and multiplying that time by the hourly rate of 15000.

You can then sum the results of the two `IF` statements to get the total pay for the time worked before and after 23:00:00